# Is there anything I can do as an end user to deal with greeting card spam sent to my personal email adress?

Tags: email, spam

Lately I've been getting a lot (well, 2-3 mails per day) of greeting card spam (I think it's called), aka spammers signing my personal email address up for contact forms and accounts with random sites, ranging from a webstore selling food supplements in the Netherlands to the City of Brighton tourism board in England. This means I'm getting random emails from a random set of addresses, but because these emails are from legitimate companies with a (thus far) good reputation, and because the only thing in these emails that might trigger spam rules is the name in the greeting line at the start of the mail (which is the vector these spammer are using to get their spam reflected), these are not at all blocked or even marked by my ISP's spam filtering.

Thus far, I'm not getting so many spam mails, so it stays manageable, but I'm worried this might escalate as spammers find more and more sites that are susceptible to greeting card spam. I've tried alerting one of the sites that was used for this, but I can't really do this for every site this happens on.

Is there anything in particular I can do about this type of spam? Beyond the nuclear "change my email address" option, which I really don't consider an option.

Comment: In short, you cannot prevent legitimate senders from emailing you

Comment: Be careful to check *all* emails.  One common tactic when an attacker is in a position to do something like transfer your money, is to flood you with 'legitimate' signup emails at the same time in order to obscure any bank notifications you may have set up.

Comment: @gowenfawr I'm not exactly concerned about bank fraud. Here in Belgium, in order to make any payments using personal banking, you either need the linked debit card and a special card reader, or you need a mobile phone app that's been linked to that debit card during setup. And I don't have any other payment methods apart from a credit card that I only use on trustworthy sources, like vetted stores and charities.